# How to extend a class having parameterized @BeforeMethod

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng

I want to extend **BaseClass** from all test cases class.
For some test cases I want to login with Admin credentials and for some with Customer.

Previously this code was working properly as launchBrowserAndLogin() method was not having any parameters.

Is there any way for extending class with parameter?

Here is my code:

```java
public class BaseClass {

    public  BaseClass() {
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void launchBrowserAndLogin(String userType) {        
        if(userType.equals("Admin")) {
            launchBrowserAndUrl(Constants.ADMIN_URL);
            login(Constants.ADMIN_USER_NAME, Constants.ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD);
        }
        if(userType.equals("Customer")) {
            launchBrowserAndUrl(Constants.CUSTOMER_TEST_URL);
            login(Constants.CUSTOMER_USER_NAME, Constants.CUSTOMER_USER_PASSWORD);
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        TestDriver.getDriver().quit();
    }
}


public class AssignEditDeleteRoleAccessibilityTest extends BaseClass {

    CreateUser newUser = new CreateUser();
    RoleAssignmentAccessValidation roleAccessValidation = new RoleAssignmentAccessValidation();

    @DataProvider(name = "AssignEditDeleteRoleAccessibilityTest")
    public static Object[] roleNames() {
        return new Object[] {Constants.AGENCY_ASSISTANT_ROLE_NAME, Constants.OPS_MANAGER_ROLE_NAME};
    }

    @Test ( priority=1, dataProvider = "AssignEditDeleteRoleAccessibilityTest")
    public void assignRoleAccessTest(String roleName) {

        newUser.createUserAssignRoleAndLogin(roleName);

        boolean isAssignRoleOptionAvailable =roleAccessValidation.assignRoleAccess();

        assertEquals(isAssignRoleOptionAvailable, false);
    }
}
```

Now I am getting error:

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod launchBrowserAndLogin
>   org.testng.TestNGException: 
>   Can inject only one of `<ITestContext, XmlTest, Method, Object[], ITestResult>` into a @BeforeMethod annotated launchBrowserAndLogin.

Comment: Not sure but `launchBrowserAndLogin()` try by changing parameter of this method to `Object` instead of `String`

Answer (score 2):

If this were my code, I would split up `BaseClass` into `AdminClass` and `CustomerClass` -- this will both solve the issue, and also help organize the tests a little better, because now you will be aware if the scenario under test is either `Customer` or `Admin` view based on which class the test case class extends:

```
public class CustomerClass {

    public  CustomerClass() {
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void launchBrowserAndLogin() {        
        launchBrowserAndUrl(Constants.CUSTOMER_TEST_URL);
        login(Constants.CUSTOMER_USER_NAME, Constants.CUSTOMER_USER_PASSWORD);       
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        TestDriver.getDriver().quit();
    }
}
```

And Admin class:

```
public class AdminClass{

    public  AdminClass() {
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void launchBrowserAndLogin() {        
        launchBrowserAndUrl(Constants.ADMIN_URL);
        login(Constants.ADMIN_USER_NAME, Constants.ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD);      
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        TestDriver.getDriver().quit();
    }
}
```

Then, your test case class can look like this:

```
public class AssignEditDeleteRoleAccessibilityTest extends CustomerClass{ // or AdminClass

    CreateUser newUser = new CreateUser();
    RoleAssignmentAccessValidation roleAccessValidation = new RoleAssignmentAccessValidation();

    @DataProvider(name = "AssignEditDeleteRoleAccessibilityTest")
    public static Object[] roleNames() {
        return new Object[] {Constants.AGENCY_ASSISTANT_ROLE_NAME, Constants.OPS_MANAGER_ROLE_NAME};
    }

    @Test ( priority=1, dataProvider = "AssignEditDeleteRoleAccessibilityTest")
    public void assignRoleAccessTest(String roleName) {

        newUser.createUserAssignRoleAndLogin(roleName);

        boolean isAssignRoleOptionAvailable =roleAccessValidation.assignRoleAccess();

        assertEquals(isAssignRoleOptionAvailable, false);
    }
}
```

This will solve your error, but I recognize this also a matter of opinion & personal design preference -- the concept of a [test fixture](https://automationintesting.com/java/junit/lessons/whataretestfixtures.html) (which is what `BaseClass` / `AdminClass` / `CustomerClass` each represent) can be implemented in many different ways. I personally believe having a fixture for each "starting" scenario is better in terms of organization and maintainability -- if `AdminClass` ever becomes more complex, this code will be out of the way from `CustomerClass`.

Another alternative would be to keep `BaseClass`, but remove the `@BeforeMethod` and `launchBrowserAndLogin()` method. Then, you can write `CustomerClass` and `AdminClass` to extend `BaseClass` (so that the `@AfterMethod` is inherited). Then, `CustomerClass` and `AdminClass()` can implement their own versions of `launchBrowserAndLogin()`, and the test case class would still look the same as this sample.

There are other approaches to resolve this as well, it's just a matter of personal preference in terms of design and maintainability.

Even if this is not your preferred answer, hopefully this at least gives you an alternative approach for future thought.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do won't be as straightforward to achieve. The `Data-Provider` feeds the `@Test` method and the `@BeforeMethod` method runs before the Test Method, so sending a parameter from the second method to the first one to run won't be possible.

Maybe helping yourself with an `ITestListener` you can work something out.

For more information on what you can parameterize in your @`BeforeMethod`, refer to the link your error is telling to look at:

https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection

There you have listed the possible things it can receive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your `BaseClass` implement `org.testng.IHookable` and then have the `run()` method invoke your `launchBrowserAndLogin()` method.

Here's how your modified base class will look like:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.IHookCallBack;
import org.testng.IHookable;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

public class BaseClass  implements IHookable {

  @Override
  public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
    Object[] parameters = testResult.getParameters();
    String userType = parameters[0].toString();
    launchBrowserAndLogin(userType);
    callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
  }

  public void launchBrowserAndLogin(String userType) {
    if (userType.equals("Admin")) {
      System.err.println("Launching Admin flow");
      launchBrowserAndUrl(Constants.ADMIN_URL);
      login(Constants.ADMIN_USER_NAME, Constants.ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD);
    }
    if (userType.equals("Customer")) {
      System.err.println("Launching Customer flow");
      launchBrowserAndUrl(Constants.CUSTOMER_TEST_URL);
      login(Constants.CUSTOMER_USER_NAME, Constants.CUSTOMER_USER_PASSWORD);
    }
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void tearDown(Method method) {
    //include your tear down logic here
    System.err.println("tearDown() for " + method.getName());
  }

  public void launchBrowserAndUrl(String url) {
     //logic goes here
  }

  public void login(String username, String password) {
     //logic goes here
  }
}
```